# NodeJS: How to handle promise rejection properly & best way to create logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, error-handling, promise

I'm pretty new to coding and to Node.JS but trying to learn... The first big difficulties I found with Node.JS was to think in an Async way when building your code, now I'm facing another monster: Promises.

Up until now, I've tried to build my code to get something to work and not minding at all the error handling (I know that's dumb, but it helps me learn) but now while running my code I get some errors from time to time.

Since "[my program](https://github.com/Ardzii/fast-crypto)" is basically (for now) a bunch of requests (using [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)) being made through infinite loops. Some manipulation of the info (`{objects}`) being received and sending it to a mongodb (via [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)), I mostly know where the errors are coming from:

- The servers (being requested) are returning an error (`statusCode !== 200`).
- Too many requests were made (which is obviously a specific `statusCode`)

And my code runs mostly smoothly, until I get one of these errors. My objective is now to get back into the code to handle properly these errors and create logs once they occur. Another ideal function would be to restart the `loop` that yielded the error (request) once they occur (maybe after a `setTimeout` or something).

My questions are:

- Could you recommend some great material on `promiseRejection` handling that I could dig into? For now I'm using `.catch((err) => { foo })` for each promise, but I'm not sure what to do with the err once caught.
- Is there out there something that helps with logs and `promiseRejection` handling (an npm package maybe)?
- How can I handle a `loop` restart? Again, I'm not expecting for you to provide a full response with the whole code (if you can that's obviously even better) but to put me in the right direction (best practices, famous npms or articles to achieve this)!

I really hope I'm not out of the topic and following SO's rule! If not let me know and I'll delete the question or edit and adapt.
Thanks in advance for your help!

******* EDIT ********

Simplifying my code:

**[]./module/apiRequest.js[]**

```
var rq = require('request-promise');
var fs = require('fs');

function apiRequest(params, req) {
  var date = new Date().toISOString();
  var logFileName = '../logs/[KRAKEN]'+date+'errorlog.txt';
  var options = {
      uri: `https://api.kraken.com/0/public/${params}`,
      qs: req,
      json: true,
      resolveWithFullResponse: true
    };
  return rq(options).then((res) => {
    if (res.statusCode === 200 && !res.body.error.length) {
      return res; // <=== THIS FOR AN UNKNOWN PARAM, THIS SERVER RETURNS A 200 WITH AN ERROR OBJECT.
    } else {
      fs.writeFile(logFileName, res, function(err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err); // <==== SINCE A 200 WON'T APPEAR AS AN ERROR I'M TRYING TO HANDLE IT THAT WAY.
        console.log(`[ERROR][KRAKEN]: log created!`);
      });
    }
  }).catch((err) => { // <==== AS FAR AS I UNDERSTAND THIS IS FOR ANY OTHER ERROR (STATUSCODE 500 FOR INSTANCE / OR AN ERROR RELATED WITH THE CODE)
    fs.writeFile(logFileName, err, function(err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(`[ERROR][KRAKEN]: log created!`);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = {
  apiRequest
};
```

**[]./module/app.js[]**

```
var apiRequest = require('./apiRequest.js').apiRequest;

function kraken(item) {
  return apiRequest('Ticker', {pair: item}).then((res) => {
      var result = {};
      var timeStamp = Math.floor(new Date());
      Object.keys(res.body.result).forEach((k) => {
        result= {
              mk: 'kraken',
              name: k,
              a: res.body.result[k].a,
              b: res.body.result[k].b,
              c: res.body.result[k].c,
              v: res.body.result[k].v,
              p: res.body.result[k].p,
              t: res.body.result[k].t,
              l: res.body.result[k].l,
              h: res.body.result[k].h,
              o: res.body.result[k].o,
              n: timeStamp,
        }
      });
      return result; // <=== THIS OCCURS WHEN THERE'S NO ERROR IN THE APIREQUEST.
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err); // <==== THIS I'M NOT SURE IF IT GETS THE ERROR BACK FROM APIREQUEST. IF I'M NOT MISTAKEN THAT'S NOT THE CASE, IT'S THE ERROR HANDLER FOR THE 'kraken' FUNCTION I'M NOT SURE WHAT KIND OF ERRORS COULD COME OUT OF THIS...
  });
};

module.exports = {
  kraken,
}
```

**[]./main.js[]**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// KRAKEN REQUIRE:
var kraken = require('./module/app.js').kraken;
var Krakentick = require('./module/model/krakenModel').Krakentick; //<=== THIS IS THE MODEL FOR MONGOOSE.

async function loopKR() {
  setTimeout(
    async function () {
      var item = ['XBTUSD']; 
      var data = await kraken(item);
      data.forEach((object) => {
            if (object.name === 'XXBTZUSD') {
              var iname =  'btcusd'
            } else {
              var iname = 'N/A' };
            var tick = new Krakentick({
              mk: object.mk,
              name: object.name,
              a: object.a,
              b: object.b,
              c: object.c,
              v: object.v,
              p: object.p,
              t: object.t,
              l: object.l,
              h: object.h,
              o: object.o,
              n: object.n,
              iname: iname,
            });
            tick.save(function(err, tick) {
              if (err) return console.log(err); //<==== THIS IS RELATED WITH MONGOOSE NOT A PROMISE IF I'M NOT MISTAKEN... THEN HANDLING WOULD OCCUR IF I HAD A PROBLEM
              console.log(`[SUCCESS][KRAKEN]: ${tick.name} added to db!`);
            });
          });
          loopKR();
        }
  }, 1100);
};

loopKR();
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to handle mainly the errors coming out of the request. But how do I send them to a log (is my current code correct? Is there a better way?)? And after the error arises and breaks the loop, how do I restart the loop automatically?

With this code, the errors are not being handled properly... For some reasons I get the following message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
>       at apiRequest.then (fast-crypto/module/app.js:34:22)
>       at tryCatcher (fast-crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (fast-crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (fast-crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (fast-crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (fast-crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (fast-crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (fast-crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (fast-crypto/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5) (node:12507) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of
>   undefined (node:12507) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code. { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '../logs/[KRAKEN]2017-08-20T10:58:03.302Zerrorlog.txt'   errno: -2, 
>   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'open',   path:
>   '../logs/[KRAKEN]2017-08-20T10:58:03.302Zerrorlog.txt' }

Comment: Please simplify your code and add to the question, without code, your question is off topic.

Comment: You only should use `.catch()` when you know what to do with the error. Like, as you mentioned, log it.

Comment: Hey @alexmac! Thanks for the tip. Simplified code added.

Comment: @Bergi the problem is that I'm not sure to understand I know all the different types of errors I can get and so what to do with the info. Basically if I can log everything and find a way to restart the loop I guess I could find better ways to handle each error and use the proper action with catch.

Comment: As currently written, the error does not break your loop. It just logs it instead of logging the success message. All this is completely unrelated to the looping.

Comment: The main issue is, `apiRequest` will always return a promise that will **resolve** to `undefined` except when `(res.statusCode === 200 && !res.body.error.length)` is true. The calling code expects an object with a `body` property, hence the failure. You handle error conditions in `apiRequest` in such a way that the `.catch` in `function kraken` would never be called as all responses from `apiRequest` are resolved promises, never rejected ones